# Put a Powershell Ouput into a variable inside a batch script

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm making following batch script

```
set FileVersion = powershell (Get-Command C:\Tool.exe).FileVersionInfo.ProductVersion

echo %FileVersion%
```

I'd like retrieve attribute 'Product Version' of file C:\Tool.exe. To  do that I use a powershell command and I want save that value to a variable called 'File Version' and later print out it, but it doesnt works!
Can you help me?

Comment: Just be aware that you may not get [the string you were expecting](https://imgur.com/u9PcCgE).

Answer (score 1):

For some yet to be understood logic, a `FOR loop` must be used.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('powershell (Get-Command C:\Tool.exe).FileVersionInfo.ProductVersion') DO (SET "FileVersion=%%~A")
```